# Camera used to work, now waiting forever to take a picture

Tags: camera, picamera

I was using my camera fine, however; today after a short travel inside its original box, when I use `raspistill ..` I get `no data received from sensor` error. I have checked the ribbon, and the led on the camera is lit as well as infrared lights at the side.

Probably some connection is loose, do you have any idea what it is?

My camera: https://www.robotistan.com/raspberry-pi-kamera-ayarli-kizilotesi-led-modulu
Raspberry Pi 3 Model B, original adapter

Comment: Had same issue. The cable was cracked at one point. Check the cable for damage.

Comment: @kwasmich Which cable do you mean? The ribbon?

Comment: check all cables

Comment: I reconnected all cables, removed screws and it didn't work at the end. I switched to another camera and it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reconnected all cables, removed screws and it didn't work at the end. I switched to another camera and it works fine.

FYI: If you came here searching this, probably your camera is dead.